# Spark sql count changes on changing case

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a table that has data distribution like :

```
sqlContext.sql( """ SELECT 
count(to_Date(PERIOD_DT)), to_date(PERIOD_DT) 
from dbname.tablename group by to_date(PERIOD_DT) """).show

+-------+----------+
|    _c0|       _c1|
+-------+----------+
|1067177|2016-09-30|
|1042566|2017-07-07|
|1034333|2017-07-31|
+-------+----------+
```

However, when I run a query like the following :

```
sqlContext.sql(""" SELECT COUNT(*) 
from dbname.tablename 
where PERIOD_DT = '2017-07-07' """).show
```

Surprisingly, it returns :

```
+-------+
|    _c0|
+-------+
|3144076|
+-------+
```

But if I changed `PERIOD_DT` to lowercase, i.e., `period_dt` , it returns the correct result

```
sqlContext.sql(""" 
SELECT COUNT(*) 
from dbname.table
where period_dt='2017-07-07' """).show
+-------+
|    _c0|
+-------+
|1042566|
+-------+
```

`period_dt` is the column on which the table is partitioned and it's type is `char(10)`

The table data is stored as Parquet :

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT                                          
   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'             
OUTPUTFORMAT                                                                   
   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
```

What might be causing this inconsistency?

Comment: what spark version are you using?

Comment: @lev Spark 1.6 with Hive 1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

It is a case sensitive issue . Because of limitations of hive meta store schema, table is always lowercase. Parquet should resolve the issue